# Why are load resistor values in common-emitter amplifiers so large?

Tags: resistance, amperage, speakers

So I have seen a few circuits for common-emitter amplifiers, like this one here.[image]

I get the function of most of the components and thir placements, but my question is, why is the load resistor at 1.2kohms? For example, I have a speaker that home that is rated on the back "8 ohms 10 watts". From that, I calculated that the speaker uses 10 volts and 1.25 amps. The 1.2kohm load resistor would only allow 0.01A through, so what am I doing wrong here? Do speakers not need that much amperage?

I do understand that the load resistor and the emitter resistor need to be large to create gain, but I don't understand how it can transmit enough power to use a large speaker.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Higher resistors set higher voltage gain. This type of amplifier would not be used to drive a loudspeaker. This is a voltage signal amplifier, not a power amplifier. Audio amplifiers normally consist of three stages, and the last one is capable of supplying high currents. Not sure how you did your power calculation. 10 Volts * 1.25A = 12.5W. But you are right that speakers need much more current than can be supplied by a circuit like this.

Comment: @mkeith Yeah, I screwed my math up pretty bad. I tried again and got 9v `1.1A, which makes more sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common-emitter amplifiers are mainly used as voltage amplifiers. If you need a lot of power, you can feed your output into a power amplifier, such as a common-collector amplifier (emitter follower). A CC amp has a high input impedance, a low output impedance, and a voltage gain near 1. The current gain depends on the load, and can be much greater than 1.

There are several different power amplifier topologies commonly used for driving loudspeakers. Look up "class A", "class B", and "class AB" for more information.