# Match Digital Amplifier to Audio Speaker

Tags: arduino, amplifier, raspberry-pi, speakers

I am working on a Raspberry pi audio project and need help creating the proper schematic.

I am given:

1. a amplifier detailed [here](https://www.mikroe.com/2x20w-amp-click)
2. a vanilla audio speaker with 5 W rated input power and 4 ohm impedance

The 20W amplifier seems to be an overkill and I am not sure how to get started on building the circuitry. Any advice is appreciated

Comment: You've linked to a module so it should be just a matter of connecting it up as shown in the datasheet. If there's no datasheet then don't buy it. You need to edit your question and add a specific answerable question rather than a vague request for advice. Otherwise your post is likely to be closed.

Comment: You better build your own amplifier it is more fun and a useful skill to know. You can start with a common emitter amplifier instead of using pp amps I really dislike op amps.

Comment: Hi @Transistor, thank you for your suggestions. I will remember that when asking questions in the future!!

Comment: Hi @HelenaWells, thank you for your encouragement! I am an electronic noob for now, but will definitely consider building my own amplifier for future projects!

Comment: @Helena, a common emitter amplifier is suitable for a pre-amplifier stage but is not suitable for a 5 W, 4 Ω load. See [Why are load resistor values in common-emitter amplifiers so large?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/194744/why-are-load-resistor-values-in-common-emitter-amplifiers-so-large/194745#194745) for example.